# how to typeset empty inner product

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, typography, delimiters

I want to typeset the following in TeX (without the arguments).

> < , >

I know that I can accomplish this by doing `\langle , \rangle`

As an example I want to write something like the follwing:

> ...The adjoints are with respect to the ( \langle , \rangle ) and not with respect to ( ( , ) )

But spacing on either side of the comma inside `\langle \rangle` does not look right.

How does one fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `$\langle {,} \rangle$` ?

Comment: `$\langle\,,\rangle$`, or what I prefer, `\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle`.

Comment: Or even `\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle`.

Comment: @Manuel the space after the comma is sure an extra one ;) (there already is one, see my answer).

Comment: @tohecz Definetly, I forgot it :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think that there are two most sensible options:

- increase the first space and make it symmetric: `$\langle\,,\rangle$`
- put `\cdot`s in place of the arguments: `$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$` (this is what I prefer).

Typeset versions:

[image]

In the second one, if you don't like the space after the comma: `$\langle\cdot{,}\cdot\rangle$`